# How do I prevent uninstall/disabling/force stopping apps in newer Android versions?

Tags: applications, uninstallation

Earlier Android versions provided the ability for apps like Applock to prevent users from disabling or force-stopping the app, but I don't believe the current version allows for this (meaning Applock will not function again until you open it). I'm looking for a way to implement this again, or at least to be able to uninstall stock apps and some method for preventing installation of new apps via .apk or the PLAY store.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. The title "prevent uninstalling apps" and the body "be able to uninstall stock apps and preventing installation" doesn't match and make the question unfocused. Could you state what you're really trying to do?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you are trying to make an Android app run all the time and protecting it from being stopped, killed, disabled, uninstalled and so on. Unfortunately Android apps are not designed to run this way. May be a system app could be made resistant against "attacks" by the user. But that would require to develop a custom ROM without root and finally re-lock the bootloader.

Comment: @Robert Earlier versions of Applock had a separate system app that had to be unlocked and deleted via a passcode in order to uninstall IIRC. I'm actually fine if it can be fully uninstalled, I'd just like to find a way to keep apps running after they've been force stopped without having to lock your entire Settings. Newer Android seems to have prevented this.

Comment: @AndrewT. Two different things, sorry.
First, I'd like to be able to uninstall stock apps.
Second, I'd like to find a way to run apps that don't kill the app entirely when you force stop, such a passcoded Applock or similar. If you "force stop" any applock on Android it will disable until that app is opened again, making those apps completely useless. I'd like it to at least be able to run (if not prevent uninstall) and retain the passcode access. I'm not sure why Android won't allow for apps that require a passcode to uninstall either.

Comment: Keeping an app alive can get pretty complicated depending on the used Android versions and the modifications by the phone manufacturer. A lot of phones and manufacturer contain very aggressive battery saving features which kill apps frequently. Read the whole sad story here: https://dontkillmyapp.com

Comment: @Robert Is there any way to add an app to a "System" list or similar to prevent it from being force-stopped? Or at least to restart it automatically if it is?